# jquery ajax request cached

Tags: jquery

when i request something via ajax if the input is the search the content seems to be cached?
do i add a random number at the end of my query?

/search?input=test

to

/search?input=test&random=283928392

i think this would solve my problem. right? how do i write this in javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the beginning of your script (before any AJAX) put:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

That will solve your problem because it will automatically add the random number for every jQuery request. If you don't use jQuery for your AJAX this won't work.

Comment: That is very sweet, I was not aware of that configuration!

Comment: It is really helpful in big projects. Any of the options on http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax can be set with this, which can really save time.

Answer (score 0):

While this [edit: Ramblingwood's Solution] solves your immediate problem, the answer to your question of how to get the number there is to use javascript's `Math.random();`

[Mozilla Reference (JavaScript 1.5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Math:random)

[MSDN Reference (JScript 8.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7944k93h.aspx)

Should be identical, but including both for completeness

Comment: Certainly your solution was the most elegant to the problem at hand (and taught me something new about jQuery), but it's important, when using any framework, I think, to remember the real functions at work here, lest the actual bare-metal of it all become lost to the ages as magic and mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

a) if you hate maths

```
  Math.random().toString().split('.')[1]
  i.e. for random number 0.3338502143216556, you will get 3338502143216556
```

b) if you wants to do maths

```
parseInt(Math.random() * 100000)
   i.e.  for random number 0.3338502143216556 you will get 33385
```

Oky my point here is to send a random integer value not a floating value, hope you don't mind :)